# How users emails/phones/addresses can be uploaded to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google AdWords there is a [simple solution](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/remarketing) for importing in JSON like way users' data.

Is there is any ability to do it an Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import data into Google Analytics via the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/data-import) - not JSON, but CSV data. Look for the section on "user data" import.

You must avoid PII, but you can use [hashed mail adresses](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en)

> You can send Google Analytics an encrypted identifier or custom
>   dimension that is based on PII, as long as you use the proper
>   encryption level. Google has a minimum hashing requirement of SHA256
>   and strongly recommends the use of a salt, with a minimum of 8
>   characters.

The problem is that you need a key field in Google Analytics that matches a column in your imported data, so the data can be attributed to existing hits. Unless you have created a viable key field at collection time you will have nothing to match the data to.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But where is API methods, that can be used to upload data? I have reviewed the link, you sent, but I couldn't find, how!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads

Answer (score 0):

Careful, [Google policies](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en) don't allow you to store personal information in Analytics.

> The Analytics terms of service, which all Analytics customers must adhere to, prohibits sending personally identifiable information (PII) to Analytics

You should read [Best practices to avoid sending Personally Identifiable Information (PII) to Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en) .

Comment: Thanks for reply! But are hashed emails personal information? I have recently found, that I can upload CID with LTV, I suppose that email hashes are practically the same.